# Fill new column in dataframe using conditional logic

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm a given the condition to fill a new column on a string which was `Game [Type A, Type B, Type C]: Played, ELSE: Status`, the idea is this if `Game` column has any of the items in the list, which is `Type A` or `Type B` or `Type C` then the new column should have the string `Played` and if `Game` has other strings which are not specified in the list, then new column should have the value in corresponding column `Status`.

`full_string = "Game [Type A, Type B, Type C]: Played, ELSE: Status"`

From the full string, I've managed to get the options list and column names and else option. The are in the following variables:

`options = ['Type A', 'Type B', 'Type C'] #this is a list`
`col_to_check = 'Game'`
`value_if_met = 'Played'`
`else_use_col = 'Status'`
`new_col_name = 'Result'`

I don't know how I can fill the `new_col_name` using the above data for the following dataframe?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
            'ID': ['AB01', 'AB02', 'AB03', 'AB04', 'AB05','AB06'],
            'Game': ['Type A','Type B','Type A','Type C','Type D','Type D'],
            'Status': ['Won', 'Draw', 'Won', np.nan, 'Won',np.nan]
    }
    )
```

The new column should have `'Result':['Played','Played','Played','Played','Won',np.nan]` for the above dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `numpy.where` function, to get the required values; use `.isin` method to check if the value of column `Game` is one of `[Type A, Type B, Type C]`, assign `Played` for `True` values, and assign `Status` column values for `False` values:

```py
>>> np.where(df['Game'].isin(['Type A', 'Type B', 'Type C']), ['Played'], df['Status'])
array(['Played', 'Played', 'Played', 'Played', 'Won', nan], dtype=object)
```

You can assign it as a new column:

```py
df['Result'] = np.where(df['Game'].isin(['Type A', 'Type B', 'Type C']),
                        ['Played'],
                        df['Status'])

     ID    Game Status  Result
0  AB01  Type A    Won  Played
1  AB02  Type B   Draw  Played
2  AB03  Type A    Won  Played
3  AB04  Type C    NaN  Played
4  AB05  Type D    Won     Won
5  AB06  Type D    NaN     NaN
```